# Why doesn't facebook see all of my images?

Tags: facebook, image, hyperlink

I've completed a quick site for a client.  She wants to know why she can't choose from all of the images when she shares the link to Facebook.  I've looked around here and found some things on 404 errors in the HTTP headers for the images.  I checked those out and everything appears to be fine.  Any ideas?

http://www.jesseleedenning.com (NSFW, she's a model)

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=jesseleedenning.com

Thanks much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yse Facebook meta tag this may helps you

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=developers.facebook.com

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="113869198637480" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Facebook Developers" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://developers.facebook.com/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yA/r/rwsSMfAU1li.png" />
```